# Can mongrel be used in production for ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongrel

Unlike Webrick, can Mongrel be used in production?  I'm looking for a small web server for Ruby on Rails that can be used locally in case of an emergency and all lines to the main webserver on the Internet are down.  I thought I could start it with a batch file like ruby script/server and webrick does.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You might as well use [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) to do this as getting Mongrel properly tuned is a bit if a fuss. You usually can't use a single Mongrel instance to handle anything other than an extremely light load, so you'll need to configure some kind of proxy balancer at the very least, and from there you'll end up having to monitor the Mongrel processes in case any die or get too bloated and need to be restarted.

Mongrel can be used in production, but it is a lot more work than Passenger.

Comment: The mongrel instance will only be on the client running.  only the single user until circumstances return to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Mongrel is not supported or being developed any more.  As another answer states you can use other products.  You could also use Unicorn which also has forking like Passenger but does not have integrated web server. For simple purposes Passenger is probably best.